# Second capturing group not capturing

Tags: java, regex, capturing-group

In java, I've been trying to parse a log file using regex. Below one line of the log file.

```
I 20151007 090137 - com.example.Main - Main.doStuff (293): ##identifier (id:21): {};
```

I need the json string at the end of the line, and the id. Which means I need two capturing groups. So I started coding.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
  "^I [0-9]{8} [0-9]{6} - com\\.example\\.Main - Main\\.doStuff \\(\\d+\\): ##identifier \\(id:(\\d+)\\): (.*?);$"
);
```

The `(.*?)` at the end of the pattern is because it needs to be greedy, but give back the `;` at the very end of the input line.

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(readAboveLogfileLineToString());
System.err.println(m.matches() + ", " + m.groupCount());
for (int i = 0; i < m.groupCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println(m.group(i));
}
```

However, above code outputs

```
true, 2
I 20151007 090137 - com.example.Main - Main.doStuff (293): ##identifier (id:21): {};
21
```

But where's my "rest" group? And why is the entire line a group? I've checked multiple online regex test sites, and it should work: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html for example sees 3 capturing groups. Maybe it's to do with the fact that I'm currently using jdk 1.6?

Comment: Note that you don't need to use a non-greedy quantifier to match `;` at the end, using a greedy quantifier `(.*)` does exactly the same with less work for the regex engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `groupCount` iteration is one of the few cases in Java where you actually need to reach the `count` value to get all groups.

In this case, you need to iterate to group `2`, since group `0` actually represents the whole match.

Just increment your counter as such (notice the `<=` instead of just `<`):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
```

The last text printed should be: `{}`

You can also skip group `0` an start your count at `1` directly, of course.

To summarize, the explicit groups marked in the `Pattern` with parenthesis start from index `1`.

See documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg).